# How to find component dependencies in noflo

Tags: noflo

Noflo seems to magically find components as long as they are installed. For example, this one:

```
# Read a file
'package.json' -> IN Read(ReadFile)
# Split the file contents by newlines
Read() OUT -> IN Split(SplitStr)
# Count the packets
Split() OUT -> IN Count(Counter)
# Send the total count to display
Count() COUNT -> IN Display(Output)

# Display also file read errors
Read() ERROR -> IN Display()
```

Is there any notion of a namespace?

This will not run for me, initially because I did not install the *strings* package and it could not find the *SplitStr* component.

How could I know that this is the package that I am missing?

Now it doesn't work because it doesn't know the *Counter* component. In general, how can I figure out which package is required by each component?

Answer (score 0):

Typically component names are in the format `libraryname/ComponentName`. The older, non-namespaced syntax also works for backwards compatibility reasons but isn't recommended for new graphs.

Answer (score 0):

The list of available components along with the packages they belong to can be found here: http://noflojs.org/component/